# Forge Laravel accessing database of another Forge Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I provisioned two servers with Laravel Forge. I'm running an Application on Server A and I wanna access a database which is on Server B.

So I configured my database like this:

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('EXTERNAL_DB_HOST', '138.31.32.33'),
    'database' => env('EXTERNAL_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('EXTERNAL_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('EXTERNAL_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
],
```

I filled in the credentials of Server B. Then I try running Tinker which uses the Connection:

```
>>>  $d = \App\Foobar::first();
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from "foobars" where "foobars"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)'
```

It gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired

I can access the Server B via Server A: `ssh forge@138.31.32.33`. I got access to that Server B.
But I'm stil getting the timeout. What am I missing? How can I access the "external" database ?

Comment: Is your project running well?

Answer (score -1):

You have to setup your Database on Server B in that way, that it can be accessed from "external". This can be done in mysql by setting up the priviliges on this mysql table and user. See the mysql manual for this:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/access-control.html

When running phpMyAdmin, there is a section for this if you have root access to the db

I hope, this will lead you in the right way ;)

Comment: It's PostgreSQL ;-)

Comment: @user1469734 Pretty sure, you will find something with a simple search like this: https://www.google.de/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSSJ6PEpp39_4_CQhcH9VGkLKeeog%3A1572518317482&source=hp&ei=rbm6XcT1GYLfwQLvoaWYAQ&q=postgresql+external+access&oq=postgresql+externa&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l2j0i203l7j0i22i30.1848.5384..6638...0.0..0.186.1451.17j1....2..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j35i39.CPuHClJqx74